# Actionscript 3 and navigateToUrl Method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a flash file with some buttons to open web addresses and I have made XML file to store my URL and then read them and parse them and assign the buttons functions to open URL:

```
btnRadio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
function()
{
    navigateToURL (radiourl , "_blank");
});
```

This code is working perfectly in flash player while development but when I publish it it does not work can anyone tell me what is the problem now?

Comment: Could pop ups be blocked from you published source?

Comment: are you executing it via the projector player, or through a browser?

Comment: I don't think that because it is run when I press CTRL + Enter, but it does not work when I publish it in browser

Comment: I believe you need to ensure allowScriptAccess is set to either "sameDomain" or "always", while embedding the swf into html.  If you are viewing the swf via a local link, file://, make sure you've given it security permissions in the flash security panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ctrl+Enter run uses the Flash player projector. When you publish to a browser, it just includes that swf in the html and displays it in the browser. Note that the Flash Player security policy restricts you in the following way:

- navigateToUrl and other http communication functions may ONLY be used when you are accessing your html from the `http/https` domains **(unless you add an exception, not recommended from the security point-of-view)**. Hence, opening the html file in your browser (which does so on the `file` domain) will violate the security constraint and the navigateToUrl will not be allowed

Comment: The ONLY part isn't true I'm afraid, simple set your local drive as exception, see my answer

Comment: Fixed the answer...meant to write that in the first place, slipped my mind, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how it is a risk to open this up from your development drive - you should only be running your own swf/htmls locally anyway.

Comment: Bingo... the operative words are **your own**. If someone gave you an swf and you saved it on your C drive and ran it, and it turned out to be rogue, then you're stuck :) Macromedia put that restriction in for a reason :)

Comment: Ok well to be honest I don't think I would run other people's SWF's. Setting up a wamp seems overkill though

Comment: But I'm using IIS or Visual Web Developer to test my asp.net site so It is actually have HTTP request object but also It does not working ,does it work in PHP and doesn't work with asp.net?

Comment: Can you edit your question as you make no mention of server side scripts in your question. As far as your original question goes, I consider that has been answered

Comment: @AmiraElsayed, as long as you are accessing over http, it will work. In your case,  I suppose you'll be running it as http://localhost/myHtml.htm or something similar (check your iis configuration)

Answer (score 3):

Goto the following site:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Click the dropdown, and then click Add Location. Add your 'C:\' your whatever happens to be your development drive where the index/swf is located.

From now on, 'navigateToUrl' will work as inteneded.